# how to display all posts Custom fields dynamically?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

```
    <?php
        foreach($getPostCustom as $name=>$value) {

            echo "<strong>".$name."</strong>"."  =>  ";

            foreach($value as $nameAr=>$valueAr) {
                    echo "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    echo $nameAr."  =>  ";
                    echo var_dump($valueAr);
            }

            echo "<br /><br />";

        }
    ?>
```

I am trying to get custom fields of particular posts. The above Code displays all Custom Fields. Please help me to retrieve only custom fields of the particular Posts Only. Thanks In Advance..

Comment: please share your full code with your custom field name and post type also.

Comment: I want to display all field values dynamically without custom field names so that it should display with respect to its posts @Shital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the entire code of my single.php file for you. Hope this works. This shows the post details and the related post_metas for me.

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 left_column"> <?php
  if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1> <?php the_title();?> </h1> <?php 
    $post_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
    foreach($post_meta as $key=>$value)
    { 
        echo "<strong>".$key."</strong>"."  =>  ";
        foreach($value as $nameAr=>$valueAr)
        {
            echo "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo $nameAr."  =>  ".$valueAr; 
        }
        echo "<br >";       
    }
    the_content(); 
    endwhile;
    endif; ?>
  </div>
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It's not working. Can you add the above code in posts query loop may be i have added in wrong place. Thanq for the help @Amit

Comment: Thanks for the help and it is working and edited as per my requirement.